# What does T_L mean in a diode datasheet?

Tags: diodes, datasheet

I am trying to compare different datasheets of the "same" component.

I do not undersand the term \$\text{T}_\text{L}\$.

[image]

Another datasheet:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

T<sub>L</sub> is the **L**ead **T**emperature. This is sometimes but not always defined in the datasheet.

Answer (score 13):

With respect to power dissipation characteristics, the **temperature of the lead frame** to which the chip is attached to the PCB or heat sink is relevant. This temperature is referred to as **T<sub>L</sub>.**

[image]

Interesting related article: [Understanding Semiconductor Thermal Resistance Data](https://www.diodes.com/design/support/technical-articles/understanding-semiconductor-thermal-resistance-data/)

> Trying to measure the thermal resistance of a specific heat flow path like junction-to-case or junction to lead is complicated by the fact that the power dissipated at the semiconductor junction leaves the package through a number of parallel heat flow paths. Each of these has a specific thermal resistance whose value depends on the dimensions and the thermal conductivity of that path."

This is why you see some parameters with assumptions like "infinite heat sink" in data sheets.